# Unable to access vbscript variable after using it in sql string - Variable is not null, but errors when used

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a block of vbscript which takes in a variable, builds a sql string with it, executes the sql string, then passes the results of the sql query along with the original variable into another sub.  It works pretty much all the time, except in one instance.  Here's the code (I added line numbers for reference... Also, I know record_source isn't used, I left it during a change I made some months ago for backwards compatibility):

```
1224    Sub UpdateContact1 (record_source, user_id)
1225        Response.Write("UpdateContact1 - user_id: " & user_id & "<br />")
1226        strSQL = "EXEC usp_GM_GetInfoForContact1 " & user_id
1227        Set rs = con.Execute(strSQL)
1228        Response.Write("UpdateContact1 after sql - user_id: " & user_id & "<br />")
1229        If Not rs.EOF Then
1230            Response.Write("UpdateContact1 inside of If<br />")
1231            Response.Write("user_id: " & user_id & "<br />")
1232            InsertFullContact1 user_id, rs("GoldMineAccountNumber"), rs("BusinessName"),     rs("FullName"), rs("LastName"), rs("Salutation"), rs("Title"), rs("WorkPhone"), rs("CellPhone"), rs("HomePhone"), rs("PrimaryFax"), rs("WorkExt"), rs("Address1"), rs("Address2"), rs("City"), rs("State"), rs("PostalCode"), rs("Country"), rs("FirstName"), rs("ReferralName"), rs("PrivateTitle"), rs("Specialty"), "", rs("GLA"), rs("GroupsDesc"), rs("RolesDesc")
1233        End If
1234    End Sub
```

Here is the result of that code:

```
UpdateContact1 - user_id: 34838
error '80020009'

/includes/gm_functions.asp, line 1228
```

Initial research suggests that error 80020009 could indicate that the variable is null.  I checked using IsNull:

```
1224    Sub UpdateContact1 (record_source, user_id)
1225        Response.Write("UpdateContact1 - user_id: " & user_id & "<br />")
1226        strSQL = "EXEC usp_GM_GetInfoForContact1 " & user_id
1227        Set rs = con.Execute(strSQL)
1228        If IsNull(user_id) Then
1229            Response.Write("user_id is null")
1230        Else 
1231            Response.Write("user_id is not null<br />")
1232            Response.Write("Length: " & Len(user_id) & "<br />")
1233        End If
1234        If Not rs.EOF Then
1235            Response.Write("UpdateContact1 inside of If<br />")
1236            Response.Write("user_id: " & user_id & "<br />")
1237            InsertFullContact1 user_id, rs("GoldMineAccountNumber"), rs("BusinessName"),     rs("FullName"), rs("LastName"), rs("Salutation"), rs("Title"), rs("WorkPhone"), rs("CellPhone"), rs("HomePhone"), rs("PrimaryFax"), rs("WorkExt"), rs("Address1"), rs("Address2"), rs("City"), rs("State"), rs("PostalCode"), rs("Country"), rs("FirstName"), rs("ReferralName"), rs("PrivateTitle"), rs("Specialty"), "", rs("GLA"), rs("GroupsDesc"), rs("RolesDesc")
1238        End If
1239    End Sub
```

And this was the output:

```
UpdateContact1 - user_id: 34838
user_id is not null
error '80020009'

/includes/gm_functions.asp, line 1232
```

Executing the stored procedure manually in SSMS using the same user_id works fine.  I'm at a loss to even understand what is happening to the variable, much less fix it.  I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks...

Comment: Exactly, what `user_id` is? What type of data does it hold? Your code is able to concat its value, does not change the variable (there is no code that modifies it) but can not retrieve the length of its content. Can you include a Response.Write of the VarType of the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this after looking at the hints provided by Pavel and doing more research on the error code.  The issue was that user_id is assigned (prior to this sub being called) to a value in another recordset which was also stored in the rs variable (which I redefine inside of this sub).  Apparently in classic asp, variables are assigned by reference rather than value... So when I changed the definition of rs, the user_id variable stopped having a value.  I resolved this by defining a new variable inside of the sub and using that to store the recordset rather than redefining rs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your issue is connected with defining variables. Let me explain why do I think so. I created a test page (test.asp)

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/gm_functions.asp"-->
<%
    UpdateContact1 "who cares", 34838
    'UpdateContact1DefineNewVar "who cares", 34838
    response.write("Finished")
 %>
```

and here is my UpdateContact1 and UpdateContact1DefineNewVar functions

```
Sub UpdateContact1 (record_source, user_id)
    Response.Write("UpdateContact1 - user_id: " & user_id & "<br />")
    strSQL = "EXEC usp_GM_GetInfoForContact1 " & user_id
    Response.Write("Hey I created a SQL query <br />")
    Set rs = con.Execute(strSQL)
    Response.Write("Hey I got some data<br/>")
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Dim some ''code
    End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateContact1DefineNewVar (record_source, user_id)
    Dim strSQL
    Dim rs    
    Response.Write("UpdateContact1DefineNewVar - user_id: " & user_id & "<br />")    
    strSQL = "EXEC usp_GM_GetInfoForContact1 " & user_id
    Response.Write("Hey I created a SQL query <br />")
    Set rs = con.Execute(strSQL)
    Response.Write("Hey I got some data<br/>")
    If Not rs.EOF Then
                Dim some ''code
    End If
End Sub
```

The outputs are:

> UpdateContact1 - user_id: 34838
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f4'
>
> Variable is undefined: 'strSQL'
>
> /includes/gm_functions.asp, line 1217

and

> UpdateContact1DefineNewVar - user_id: 34838 **Hey I created a SQL query**
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: ''
>
> /includes/gm_functions.asp, line 1232

So this **Hey I created a SQL query** makes me think that variables you are using are not defined (include file is missing?). I'm not a expert in vbscript, but I hope it will help you.

### UPDATE

I extended the code by adding Response.Write(VarType(strSQL))

So the first output was

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f4' **Variable is undefined**:
>   'UpdateContact1' /test.asp, line 5

and the second was

> **0** UpdateContact1DefineNewVar - user_id: 34838 Hey I created a SQL query Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: ''
>   /includes/gm_functions.asp, line 1221

and **0** means vbEmpty - Indicates Empty (uninitialized) http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_vartype.asp

Comment: strSQL and rs are both defined and used in the asp page which includes the one this sub is in.  They are used there, and then this sub re-uses them.

Comment: @Redit0 Not sure... Why do I see different results? If I'm right it fails at the line 1226. I think you can easily check it by creating new variables for *strSQL*,*rs* and *con*

Answer (score -1):

We'd need to see the stored proc to be sure, but might it be expecting a varchar string, not the numeric you're passing in?

Change your SQL string assembly line to the following:

```
strSQL = "EXEC usp_GM_GetInfoForContact1 '" & user_id & "'"
```

and see if that cures it.

Comment: The stored proc worked as expected.  That was my first thought, even though the error occurred on the line AFTER the one executing the proc.. to test it, I manually executed the sql query using the same user_id.